# Excel chart with countries in y-axis, % in x-axis, circles as markers and control groups

Tags: excel, charts, statistics

Do you know if this chart, as shown in the following image, can be done in Excel?

Chart:

[image: Cost of Living Index image chart]

I don't even know how this kind of chart is named, so I cannot search in the web for tutorials. I don't need to display three points on every row as in this chart (one is enough), and even I can mark the control group manually.

Comment: It's commonly referred to as a Dot Plot (as distinct from a Scatter Plot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done in Excel.

If you want vertical orientation like on the picture above, then you should probably use the Scatter chart with quite some modifications. You would set the x values of the series to your values and the y values can be just 1,2,3,4,5.... The biggest problem with this approach would be how to display the correct categories. There is a tool to help you do that and it is discussed here: https://superuser.com/questions/485883/how-to-create-dynamic-scatter-plot-matrix-with-labels-and-categories-on-both-axi

For horizontal one you can use a normal line chart - with hidden line and only markers visible (Excel doesn't support vertical line graphs).

Even three groups are easy to do, you just need to add three series and format them accordingly.

The lines are also quite easy to do, you add minor / major gridlines to the chart and then format those as well.

Comment: Thx Mitja. I followed your advise about using horizontal orientation. The result is not identical but still you can observe the trend (http://agustin-suarez.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/penetracion-linkedin-hispano-hablantes-social-media.png). The problem with the scattered chart and vertical orientation is that I ended with a big height, which is not situable for blog articles.